# How to search twitter by location?

Tags: twitter, search

How do I search for Tweets sent from a Location?

[Twitter help says](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-advanced-search) there's a Place tab in Advanced Search. But there is none.
I've tried Place:$place  and Location:location but that is a plain text search.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geocode: longitude, latitude,radiusmi

Example:
This is a search within 200mi of an area just west of Denver;

geocode:39.416535,-105.781204,200mi

[View this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=geocode%3A39.416535%2C-105.781204%2C200mi%20&src=typed_query&f=live)

[Source:](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rules-and-filtering/search-operators)

> **Geolocalization**: the search operator “near” isn’t available in the
> API, but there is a more precise way to restrict your query by a given
> location using the geocode parameter specified with the template
> “latitude,longitude,radius”, for example, “37.781157,-122.398720,1mi”.
> When conducting geo searches, the search API will first attempt to
> find Tweets which have lat/long within the queried geocode, and in
> case of not having success, it will attempt to find Tweets created by
> users whose profile location can be reverse geocoded into a lat/long
> within the queried geocode, meaning that is possible to receive Tweets
> which do not include lat/long information.

Comment: what if the poster was using VPN? which IP address will it show